# Не учитывать первую часть из split

Tags: java, split

У меня есть массив емейлов, мне нужно из них вытащить только домены. Как с помощью метода split не учитывать или удалить строку, которая идет до знака @?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понимаю:

```
ArrayList<String> EMAILS = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("example@gmail.com", "example@gmail.com", "example@gmail.com"));

for(int i=0;i<EMAILS.size();i++) {
  EMAILS.set(i, EMAILS.get(i).split("@")[1]); 
}
```

Comment: Скажи, пожалуйста, а зачем `.size() - 1` и почему без пробелов и зачем длинный отступ в 8 пробелов в начале каждой строчки?

Comment: @diraria Ошибся. Я не знаю как форматировать тут текст. я копирую с отступами.

Comment: Ну смотри, насколько я знаю, должно быть либо `i < size`, либо `i <= size - 1`, но не `i < size - 1` (потому что тогда, например, если в массиве один элемент, то есть `size == 1`, то цикл ни разу не выполнится). Насчёт отступов, давай расскажу, как можно сделать чтобы было без них! Копируешь текст с отступами (допустим там будет 4*3=12 пробелов), потом выделяешь весь код и нажимаешь ctrl+k пока не останется только четыре пробела.

Comment: И ещё, расскажи, пожалуйста, если не секрет, почему не ставишь пробелы вокруг `<`, `=` и после `;`

Comment: @diraria на счет `size` ошибся. У каждого свой подход, каждый пишет как ему удобно. пробелы делают более читабельным код, ну а так суть не меняется.

Comment: @diraria Спасибо за подсказку)